# Count number of Rows with the same value in a Column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have these two entity with their attributes:

> > book - book_id, book_name, author_id, editor_id, subject_id, isbn
> >
> > author - author_id, fn, ln

I have to query the author with the most number of rows
here's the attributes and entity:

```
| book_id | book_name   | author_id |  editor_id |  isbn     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 | Book1 Title |  Author1  |  Editor1   | 8000-9000 |
|       2 | Book2 Title |  Author2  |  Editor1   | 8000-9001 |
|       1 | Book1 Title |  Author1  |  Editor1   | 8000-9002 |
|       3 | Book2 Title |  Author2  |  Editor1   | 8000-9003 |
```

```
| author_id |  fn    |    ln    |
---------------------------------
|       1   | name1  |  lname1  |
|       2   | name2  |  lname2  |
|       3   | name3  |  lname3  |
```

and here is my code:

```sql
SELECT author.author_id, author.fn, author.ln, COUNT(DISTINCT book.editor_id) as num
FROM `editor`, `book`
GROUP BY `editor_id`
LIMIT 0,1
```

but off-course i don't get what I want.
The output must be:

```
| author_id |  fn    |    ln    |
---------------------------------
|       1   | name1  |  lname1  |
```

since the "author_id = 1" has 2 entries on books.

Comment: Why `author_id` varchar in books table? isn't that should be int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one but please take note that I converted the `author_id` from `varchar` to `int`):

```
SELECT book_count,a.author_id,a.fn, a.ln 
FROM author a
JOIN
(
  SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c
  GROUP BY c.author_id
) b 
ON a.author_id = b.author_id
ORDER BY book_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/336d6/16).

Comment: @user2497414: You see the `inner sub query`? the `SELECT COUNT(*) book_count` is the `book_count` you need not include that on your book fields.

Comment: oh i see but still the result isn't the most number of rows that have the same value in the column. the result was the highest number in author_id.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate more the specs? I think the output is correct. Have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: the result was "author_id = 3" since it has the highest number. not "author_id = 1" which has the most number of count

Comment: How come it should be 3? I don't get it. Can you provide more data?

Comment: it should be the author_id that has author_id=1, but the result i get using this query was author_id that has author_id=3

Comment: this is my query:
`mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(b.book_count), a.* 
   FROM author a INNER JOIN(
     SELECT COUNT(*) book_count,author_id FROM book
     GROUP BY author_id) b 
   ON a.author_id = b.author_id
   LIMIT 1")or die ('Query Failed');`

Comment: i changed the value in the fiddle and the result turn out to be wrong. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e4e7